# Serving a iframe content from Ember app during development

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've a `public/uploads/...` folder in my Ember app intended to hold all of my user's uploaded files. It includes images, videos as well as some `.html` files that I want to serve via an `iframe` in the app.

I'm trying to serve these iframes in a component:

```
<iframe src="/public/uploads/folder/file.html">
```

The development serve is presumably receiving requests for the `file.html` and checking the router as it looks like a normal `GET` request as opposed to an asset. This correctly leaves me with an error:

> Uncaught UnrecognizedURLError

Is there any way to tell the `ember-cli` dev server that I want it to serve that particular folder?

Comment: Are you using ember-cli-mirage?  
If so you should add:  
`this.passthrough('/public/uploads/folder/**');`
to mirage/config.js

Comment: Thanks. I had actually tried that but it doesn't work. As far as I can tell, this request isn't getting to Mirage as the router is recognising it as a page request and then not finding it in my routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best to keep the uploads outside of the `public` folder e.g. in a separate `uploads` folder.

To tell the dev server to serve a particular folder, run the command:

```
 ember g server
```

This will generate a `server/index.js` that you can then customise.

Add the following lines inside the exported function:

```
var express = require('express');
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname + "/../uploads"));
```

Lastly, install the express dependency if you're not already using it:

```
npm install express --save-dev
```

Now, after starting the Ember dev server any files in the `uploads` folder can be served.

Comment: This works perfectly. What exactly is going on though? From what I can tell, `server/index.js` allows us to customize the development server `ember-cli` runs and we're telling it to use express when it sees requests to `/upload/...`?